# IIS7 - How do I update the alias after site creation?

Tags: iis-7

I have a web application directory (subsite of the main - default website).  I want to update the Alias that I originally chose.  How do I do it in IIS7?

---

In the file mentioned by Coding Gorilla I see

```
<application path="/SiteAlias" applicationPool="DefaultAppPool">
```

and

```
 <location path="Default Web Site/SiteAlias">
```

do I need to update both of these?

Comment: Can you define "Alias"?

Comment: `http://site/alias`  Essentially its what I would call the alias to access the virtual directory.  Though, I'm not sure if virtual directories exist anymore in IIS7.

Comment: Ok, so you just want to change the directory name. Are you wanting to do this with the IIS console or do you not have that access?  (And yes, they still exist)

Comment: I typically use start > run > inetmgr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't actually do this thru the IIS Manager console, but what you can do is edit the `C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config' file.  Find the related``node and update the`path` attribute.

Comment: Ah,that's pretty disappointing that it can't be done through the GUI.

Comment: Yea, I thought you could as well, but I tried and wasn't able.

Comment: I had to open it with regular Notepad as Notepad++ was unable to save the edits using 64 bit OS: [unable-to-save-applicationhost-config-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280076/unable-to-save-applicationhost-config-file)